# Can't converting text from english to hindi in android app

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, typeface

I am building a app which search names from arraylist and show results what we searched in edittext. my arraylist contains names in hindi font and i want to use default english font in edittext.  also below i kept textview which must shows text in hindi which i typed in edittext. see my code :

`Typeface hindi = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/hindifont.ttf"); textview.setText(edittext.getText().toString()); textview.setTypeface(hindi);`

but it not showing hindi font in textview instead it showing english same as in edittext.

Comment: can you try by writing this `textview.setText(edittext.getText().toString());` after `setTypeface(hindi)`

Comment: tried didn't worked